# Show that $\frac { 1} {z \sin z } $ has a simple pole at $z= \pi $

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I show that $\frac { 1} {z \sin z } $ has a simple pole at $z= \pi $

The definition I'm working with is that $f $ has a simple pole of order m at $z _0 $ if $f $ in some punctured neighborhood of $z _0 $ equals $\frac {g(z) } {(z-m)^m } $ where $g $ is analytic at $z _0 $ and $g(z _0 )\neq 0$.

If I multiply the series expansion at $z = \pi $ of $\frac {1 } {\sin z } $ with $(z- \pi ) $ I think the new series converge to $\frac {1 } {\cos z } $ around $\pi $. Is this right?

Thus $\frac {1 } {(z-\pi) }\frac {z-\pi } {z \sin z } $ would be analytic at $\pi $ and this would imply a simple pole.

Is there other, better ways to determine this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $$\lim_{z\to\pi}\frac{z-\pi}{z\sin(z)}$$

Comment: Reciprocal has a simple zero (check its derivative).

Comment: Ok, so the answer would be to the reciprocal $zsinz $ is zero at $\pi $. But its derivative is not, so that the reciprocal has a simple zero at $\pi $. Then use the charachteristic that if the reciprocal of a function $f $ has a zero of order m att a point, then $f $ has a pole of order m at this sime point.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z-\pi=t$ therefore we have $\frac{1}{z\sin z}=\frac{1}{(t+\pi)\sin(t+\pi)}=-\frac{1}{(t+\pi)\sin(t)}$  so that $$\lim\limits_{t\to0}(-\frac{t}{(t+\pi)\sin(t)})=-\frac{1}{\pi}$$ this shows that $0$ is a simple pole and $\pi$ so is.